# OutOfMemory in MicroPython

Tags: micropython

I use MicroPython on my Raspberry Pi Pico and try to display a BLOB coming from an HTTP API on a Waveshare ePaper display. This is my code:

```py
epd = EPD_7in5_B()
epd.Clear()

while(True):
    response = urequests.get('http://<<myRaspiPicoW>>/screenshotCreator/latestImage?blackAndWhite=true&asWaveshareBytes=true')
    if response.status_code == 200:
        epd.buffer_black = response.content
        epd.display()
    else:
        print('Request failed')

    epd.sleep()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Running this code works pretty nice, but since I want to update the display every couple of minutes, I'm running into an OutOfMemory exception for the second run:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 283, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 20, in content
MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 11520 bytes
```

The line throwing the exception is `epd.buffer_black = response.content`. From what I learned about MicroPython I could imagine that `response.content` is somehow kept in memory after the loop run, so I played around with `del response` or `gc.collect()`, but no luck.

I also saw that `urequests` has the option to access the [raw response content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content). From C# I'm familiar with stream APIs to copy bytes from one array to another. Is there a similar API for `bytearray`, e. g.:

```py
i = 0
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
    epd.buffer_black.write(chunk, i * 128)
    i++
```

So how can I work around this problem, e. g. by freeing memory or using a stream API?

Comment: You're holding a reference to the 'previous content' in epd.buffer_black while you are collecting the 'current content' - right up to the point at which the assignment to buffer_black is complete: i.e., you will have two lots of content in memory.  Do you really need to have buffer_black always set?

Comment: Ah you mean I could set `epd.buffer_black` to `None` after `epd.display()`?

Comment: You'll have to tell me!  I don't know whether the ePaper thing needs to retain its buffer_black value after the display() call returns.  Worth a try, though.  (Edited) Oh, I see you did.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by resetting the `epd.buffer_black` after each iteration with an empty `bytearray`. This is my final code:

```py
epd = EPD_7in5_B()
epd.Clear()
empty_buffer = bytearray(0)

while(True):
    response = urequests.get('http://<<myRaspiPicoW>>/screenshotCreator/latestImage?blackAndWhite=true&asWaveshareBytes=true')
    if response.status_code == 200:
        epd.buffer_black = response.content
        epd.display()
    else:
        print('Request failed')

    epd.sleep()
    epd.buffer_black = empty_buffer
    response = None
    time.sleep(30)
```

Kudos to @arfur-narf for pointing this out

Comment: Might be  worth setting 'response' to None at the same point.